# Website deployed on Azure need Disaster Recovery and High Availability

Tags: azure, high-availability, disaster-recovery

I have site deployed on Azure. I am using Cloud Services, Storage, SQL Database.

I want to have High Availability and Disaster Recovery for our Azure Website.

My question is that how can we provide this feature on Azure?  Is it already managed by Azure or we need to use any services from Azure for the same.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't think DR is needed, since everything you use is PaaS Service, so if you trust Azure - it will handle everything for you, if you don't. Well, if you don't it won't help you ;)

So, in my opinion best way to achieve what you are looking for is using build-in HA for Cloud Services (increase instance count), while Storage and Azure SQL are HA by design.

If you really-really want DR, you can implement Traffic Manager with extra copy of your Cloud Service in another Azure region and implement Storage Replication and Azure SQL Replication.

I won't be giving link to documentation, as all of those are found in under 5 minutes in and search engine.